# StreamedContent to representing imagepath

Tags: jakarta-ee, primefaces, jsf-2.2

In the PrimeFaces showcase (PF5), the following example

```
<p:imageCompare leftImage="/resources/demo/images/compare/lara-ps3.png"
    rightImage="/resources/demo/images/compare/lara-ps4.png"
    width="450" height="435"/>
```

uses static resources as images. I would like to be more dynamic through the StreamedContent. But the attributes only accept Strings as attribute-value.

Question: How do I "convert" the StreamedContent to the corresponding String.

I know, I could write the image to a file, but this seems not to be very sexy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already tried using expression language?

xhtml page:

```
<p:imageCompare leftImage="#{imageBean.leftImage}"
    rightImage="#{imageBean.rightImage}"
    width="450" height="435"/>
```

managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
public class ImageBean {
    private StreamedContent leftImage;
    private StreamedContent rightImage;

    public ImageBean() {
        InputStream stream1 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("lara-ps3.jpg");  //or something else
        leftImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream1, "image/jpeg");

        InputStream stream2 = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("lara-ps4.jpg");  //or something else
        rightImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream2, "image/jpeg");
    }

    public StreamedContent getLeftImage() {
        return this.leftImage;
    }

    public StreamedContent getRightImage() {
        return this.rightImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this was my first approach. The renderer will not render this the way I want, the result in the src-attribute in the img tag is something like `http://localhost:8080/core.ui.dyn/org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent@208343c6`
(Btw: I got the images from a database)

Comment: @user1139597 did you get any response for this? I'm having the same problem. StreamedContent for p:graphicImage works but not for p:imageCompare. Is this a limitation?